# Running formula inside of the script or writing the equivalent in js

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Based on one cell in my spreadsheet I'm trying to fill my other cells with data. This is what I'm after…

```
A1 = date #1 (Only value entered manually in the spreadsheet)
A2 = date #2 (based on A1)
A3 = date #3 (based on A1)
A4 = value #1 (based on A2)
A5 = value #2 (based on A3)
```

In a spreadsheet cell A2 is calculated like so (If A1 is not a weekday then get the previous weekday):

```
=WORKDAY(A1+1, -1)
```

In a spreadsheet cell A3 is calculated like so: (If A1+1month is not a weekday then get the previous weekday):

```
=WORKDAY(EDATE(A1, 1)+1, -1)
```

A4 is based on the results of A2 like so:

```
A4 = getA4(A2); //The getA4-function is already written
```

A5 is based on the results of A3 like so:

```
A5 = getA5(A3); //The getA5-function is already written
```

One solution would be to:

```
1. Read the A1 cell to the script
2. Write the two WORKDAY formulas to the spreadsheet from the script.
3. Read the values of A1 and the now generated A2 and A3 cells from the spreadsheet.
4. Send the values of A2 and A3 to the getA4 and getA5-methods
5. Then write the resulting values to the spreadsheet using setFormulas(newRangeWithAllOfTheValues);
```

My question:

Since I'm trying to minimize reading/writing to the spreadsheet I would like to do this in only one read/write. So I would like to either:

A) ...translate the two WORKDAY functions into JS-functions so that I can call getA4 and getA5 directly, or...

B) ...run the two WORKDAY functions inside of the script (if it's even possible) so that I can get the results in variables and then call getA4 and getA5 directly.

And I don't know how to do either...

Comment: I ended up going with the solution I proposed. It's an extra read/write but the execution time was only 1sec extra so it's OK.